# I have a Transaction Hash, how to get the readable Input Data?

Tags: ether, etherscan, hash

i have a Transaction Hash:
0x9f46760404dd3075533e8360fe4beb0ba7210423af1f4a95a5c80defffe824b5, for
how do i decode the "input data" easily?

for example:
https://www.blockchain.com/eth/tx/0x9f46760404dd3075533e8360fe4beb0ba7210423af1f4a95a5c80defffe824b5

i tried this, but i don't have the ABI:
https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://testing.mnedelchev.me/decode-tx-input.html).

Or if you want to use web3, there is method inside the library called `web3.utils.toAscii(<INPUT>)`.

Comment: Thank you Miroslav! I just tried the link, i pasted the hash 0x9f46760404dd3075533e8360fe4beb0ba7210423af1f4a95a5c80defffe824b5 into the form, it replied Wrong Hash. Did i miss anything?

Comment: @yts61 wierd, take a look on my video - https://streamable.com/3gj4dh . Everything runs well?

Comment: @yts61 Please try again, issue should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Miroslav, it works like charm! the URL reads "testing", are you removing this web app later?